# Personal URL for website premium members

Tags: php, url

I'm building a website that lets you view a members (Basic Member) profile with a url of say, http://www.website.com/user.php?id=123456789, which is fine for what I'm doing, but for premium members I'd like to give them a more personalised url, say for example:

> website.com/user.php?id=123456789 ==
>   website.com/username

Does anyone know how this is possible, bearing in mind that it is ONLY for premium members - Basic members still use user.php?id=123456789

Comment: htaccess is all you need

Comment: to achieve something like this is called a friendly URL which basically hides website.com/user.php?id=123456789 and using as mentioned above the htaccess file to interoperate the sent url to the correct one etc

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate of the question identified by Quentine - but the 2 answers are very poor.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has downvoted Prodikl's answer - but it does start with the key question: what resources/access do you have to change this? As a minimum you'll need some control over your webserver config - and we'd need to know which webserver it is to give specific advice. PHP does not control the mapping of URLs to scripts - that role is carried out by the webserver. With *some* framewaorks it is possible to do further routing within the PHP code - but the webserver still needs to direct the request to the right script to start with.

Without any such access to change the webserver config then you're only option is to create a directory for each username in the document root and put an index.php in each one.

A further question is whether you **must** have the url in the format `website.com/${username}` - this is rather tricky and can only be acheived by implementing your 'router' as a 404 handler. OTOH if `website.com/somedir/${username}` then you've got more choices - you can use mod_rewrite to rewrite `website.com/somedir/${username}` as `website.com/user.php?id=${username}` (you can also create a database listing one to one mappings instead of to a common script).

There's lots of question and answers here on how to solve the problem using mod_rewrite.